# How to create a Vue Tooltip component using BootstrapVue tooltip

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, bootstrap-vue

I'm new to Vue and I don't use Bootstrap often so please pardon my newbie question, I'm trying to create a Vue tooltip component, I've created one to behave the way I wanted using css, however, I'm running into some accessibility issues, so I decided to use the BootstrapVue tooltip instead, but I don't know how I would create this component with Bootstrap.
This is basically my Tooltip.vue component using css:

```
<template>
      <div :class="`tooltip ${position}`">
        <slot></slot>
        <span class="tooltip-text">{{content}}</span>
      </div>
</template>

<script>  
export default {
  name: 'Tooltip',


  props: {
    position: String,
    content: String,
  }

};
</script>

<style lang="scss">
.tooltip {
.......
</style>
```

Then I import and use my component in other places like this:

```
<tooltip position="right" content="Right tooltip">Hover me</tooltip>
```

And I have created a TooltipBootstrap.vue component wanting to have the same structure but using Bootstrap, but I don't know how that would go, here is what I started:

- I npm installed bootstrap-vue

  ```
   <template>
   <div>
      <button v-b-tooltip.hover.${position}="'${content}'"></button>
    </div>
   </template>

  <script>

    import VBTooltip from 'bootstrap-vue';

    export default {
      name: 'TooltipBootstrat',

        components: {
          VBTooltip,

      },
      props: {
        position: String,
        content: String,
      }

    };
    </script>
  ```

I'm reading the bootstrap documentation: https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/directives/tooltip, but I don't know if I'm using this the way it's supposed to be used, so I'm a little lost and would appreciate any help/advice, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

BootstrapVue provide `<b-tooltip>` component and `v-b-tooltip` directive (preferred method from [document](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/tooltip#tooltips)). You can play around in the document.

In simple words, you can use `v-b-tooltip` directive on any element which is very convenient. but for `<b-tooltip>` component you have to set `target` to identify the target to active the tooltip.

So in your case you can do something like:

```html
<template>
  <div v-b-tooltip="{ title: content, placement: position }"> 
    <slot></slot>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { VBTooltip } from 'bootstrap-vue'

export default {
  name: 'Tooltip',
  directives: {
    'b-tooltip': VBTooltip,
  },
  props: {
    position: String,
    content: String,
  }
};
</script>
```